# Convert audio stream into image

Tags: audio, converters, spectrogram

I'm working on a machine learning project so I have TONS of data. My model is to train based on audio data. Let's say it comes from mp3 or mp4.

Do you know any programs that do mass conversion from audio to some sort of image? Like a spectrogram?

I know there are programs that visualize individual files, but are there any that I can simply input a directory and it will convert all files?

Comment: Would this work for you? http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/200168/how-to-create-the-spectrogram-of-many-audio-files-efficiently-with-sox